# Parsing a char in to typedef union array

Tags: c

I have a union of two structs,

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ssid[32];      /**< SSID of target AP*/
    uint8_t password[64];  /**< password of target AP*/
    bool bssid_set;        /**< whether set MAC address of target AP or not. Generally, station_config.bssid_set needs to be 0; and it needs to be 1 only when users need to check the MAC address of the AP.*/
    uint8_t bssid[6];     /**< MAC address of target AP*/
    uint8_t channel;       /**< channel of target AP. Set to 1~13 to scan starting from the specified channel before connecting to AP. If the channel of AP is unknown, set it to 0.*/
} wifi_sta_config_t;

typedef union {
    wifi_ap_config_t  ap;  /**< configuration of AP */
    wifi_sta_config_t sta; /**< configuration of STA */
} wifi_config_t;
```

And i'm trying to achieve something like this,

```
char* ssid = "MYSSID";
char* psw = "MYPSW";

wifi_config_t sta_config = { .sta = { .ssid = {ssid}, .password = {psw}, .bssid_set = 0 } };
```

I even tried this, but no luck,

```
uint8_t ssid[32] = {"MYSSID"};
uint8_t psw[64] = {"MYPSW"};

wifi_config_t sta_config = { .sta = { .ssid = {ssid}, .password = {psw}, .bssid_set = 0 } };
```

But above doesn't work and gives me `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Whats wrong am i doing here?

Any help would really appreciated.

EDIT:

Hardcoding values to struct union works fine,

```
wifi_config_t sta_config = { .sta = { .ssid = {"MYSSID"}, .password = {"MYPSW"}, .bssid_set = 0 } };
```

Above code compiles/runs fine, But i want to change the `ssid` and `password` programmatically. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Use `#define` . The initializer for an array cannot be another array, unfortunately

Comment: @M.M ehh? `char arr[] = "This is an array";`..what about this?

Comment: @M.M thank you for the prompt response, Would you mind showing that in a piece of code?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I tried `char arr[] = "This is an array";` as well, But it gives me `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast`.

Comment: PrasadDeZoysa that was not for you.... I'm just trying to clarify my understanding with @M.M sir.

Comment: @SouravGhosh In that case the string literal isn't really a string literal, it's just an alias for `{ 'T', 'h', 'i', 's', ... 'a', 'y', '\0' }`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, but I thought it's an array, an unnamed array, for that matter, but it __is__ an array, as we can see using `sizeof` also, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, if you use a string literal in any other context it's an array. But not when used to initialize an array of characters on definition of the array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK sir, any reference for that? I usually thought the other way, on most of the cases, a string literal will decay to the pointer to the 1st element, but for `sizeof`, initialization of array and operand for `&`, for these three, a string literal __will be__ an array. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry, I meant it cannot be an identifier which is the identifier of an array

Comment: @SouravGhosh The C11 specification (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E)), §6.7.9 paragraph 32 (example 8): "`char s[] = "abc"` ... This declaration is identical to `char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }`"

Comment: @M.M, i need to assign values of the variable throughout the program, so i think i'm out of the `#define` option?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sir, as I read it, the declaration is identical, means the declaration are same as considered for `s` and `t`. But that does not mean that the initializers are identical. Both the initializers initialize the target arrays with same content (value), but does that mean that the initializers themselves are same?

Comment: @PrasadDeZoysa I dont' know what you are trying to say sorry, perhaps you could update your question to show the other usages you need to support

Comment: @M.M, Please see the edited question.

Comment: @PrasadDeZoysa It's still unclear what you are asking. You can still set a string literal later on.  It would help to show, using actual code, what you mean by "change the ssid and password programmatically"

Comment: You can later change the value with `strcpy(sta_config.sta.ssid, "OTHERSSID");` if that's what you mean

Comment: @M.M, That is exactly what i meant, But i tried that too, unfortunately it gives me an error `error: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' differ in signedness`. Which is obviously because of `struct` param is not a string?

Comment: @PrasadDeZoysa It is because of `uint8_t ssid[]`. Simply cast it to a `char*` before passing it to strcpy.

Comment: Thank you @M.M & Lundin that was the case. Now it works without any problem.

Comment: ^ or use `char ssid[]` in the first place, since it is meant to be readable characters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot initialize an array with another array in C. This is a (weird) syntax restriction in C. Code such as `.ssid = {ssid}` will therefore not work.

You can however copy arrays that are part of structs/unions. Very inconsistent. Therefore, to initialize a struct/union, you can use a *compound literal* that creates a struct/union (code not tested):

```
wifi_config_t sta_config = 
  (wifi_config_t) 
  { 
    .sta = 
    { 
      .ssid = "MYSSID", 
      .password = "MYPSW", 
      .bssid_set = 0 
    } 
  };
```

Comment: The `(wifi_config_t)` is unnecessary

Comment: Still my question stands, I want to assign the MYSSID value programmatically, How can i do that?

Comment: @M.M Indeed, on the initialization line. But if you wish to do the same during assignment, it is needed.

Comment: @PrasadDeZoysa `strcpy` then.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for answer today and finally found it out. As it was previously said, you need to use strcpy instead of assigning it. But you need to use cast (char *), here is example

```
char * myssid = "example";
strcpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.ssid,myssid);
```